# Is there a way to import a file into Github without using the desktop version or command line?

Tags: github, chromebook

Is there a way to import a file into Github without using the desktop version or a command line? Can you just select a file from a computer? If there is a way then it will be much easier for people with Chromebooks to use Github.
[Add a file to github picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSCFw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the upload file function?

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/

On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

```
1) Under your repository name, click Upload files.
2) Drag and drop the file or folder you'd like to upload to your repository onto the file tree.
3) At the bottom of the page, type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file.
4) Below the commit message fields, decide whether to add your commit to the current branch or to a new branch. If your current branch is master, you should choose to create a new branch for your commit and then create a pull request.
```

Comment: Yes, @Loofer, but when I create a new repository I only see options for quick setup and no import files button.

Comment: When you create the repo in github click the "add readme" checkbox and it will create a git repo for you and you can then add files.